# Where should the Altium board origin location be?

Tags: altium

Where should the location of the origin should be in a PCB design? I usually throw it on the bottom left corner of the PCB board edge and try to keep all items in positive quadrants (for no good reason).

I'm wondering if there are any justifications for its placement elsewhere. For example, in the case of a PCB that has a board-to-board connection that the origin be set to some critical mechanical feature to datum off of for mating.

Comment: There are many cases to place the origin in other locations besides the bottom left. It depends on use case, product design, enclosure, manufacturing needs, etc. There's not really a single "right" answer, just "it depends."

Comment: On a round board, I'd put it in the center :)

Comment: I think having all positive coordinates is good enough reason.  I place it lower left corner too

Comment: @KyleB At my company we have many symmetrical board designs where having negative coordinates that correspond with another component with a positive coordinate  helps simplify design and error-checking. But obviously that is just one use case.

Comment: @JYelton  I can see how that would make sense.    In my company, with about 400-500 boards behind me, I can't recall a single one ever being symmetrical!!!   You have indeed identified a reason it would matter where the origin is.   You should put that as answer because it is one!

Comment: I feel Spehro adequately covers symmetry in his answer, I recommend you accept that one! Also, I've edited your question to avoid asking for opinions (off-topic on this site) and retracted my close vote which was due to the perceived opinion query. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often move it around during layout, especially if the board has some kind of symmetry.

For example, you might be locating objects relative to a panel edge so you might put the origin off the board entirely. Or if the board has mounting holes and a display symmetrical about the center, move it to the center in one dimension.

That way the mounting holes might be at X= -50mm and X = +50mm and it's easy to check.

Generally, I think the center on something that lines up to mechanical parts is easier that using an edge.